# Different settings for form & table views in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, alias

In QGIS 3.18. Layer properties-->Attributes Form allows changing various aspects of attribute visualization and entry/editing, including **aliases**, **widgets** (for drop-down menus, checkboxes, etc), and **constraints**.

These settings affect how the data is visualized in all, or nearly all, data views.

For example: for a field called `"Species1"`, I may wish to assign it an alias of `"High Priority Species"` for my data entry form.

However, this field is now titled `"High Priority Species"` on *all data views* including 1) all 'sets' (tabs) of fields in the form, 2) the Identify Features box, and most inconveniently, 3) **the attribute table**, both in the column titles and in the drop-down menu for entering a field expression.

I would like to be able to choose different settings for different views -- especially, for form vs. table views. In this example, I would like to turn the alias off for viewing a short field name in the attribute table, and still have my alias visible in my data entry form.

Is this currently possible in QGIS?