# Exclude aliases from attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, alias

This is related to [this unanswered question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/416499/different-settings-for-form-table-views-in-qgis) which is broader; my hope is that this narrower, more specific question may get an answer.

In QGIS 3.18, I would like to assign **aliases** to certain fields (via layer properties--> attributes form). However, I would like the aliases to render exclusively in *form view*, and not also in the *attribute table*, which is happening at the moment.

I want the forms to render the aliases, and attribute table headers to render the actual field names.

Is this currently possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

you can use datadefined override for that - but anyway I am wondering, that it is working....

1. Add a layer variable to the layer (layerproperties), for example form='test2'
   [image]
2. use data defined override for the alias and use the variable

[image]

3. the Alias will then only be visible in the form, not in the table

[image]

Comment: Interesting, checking this option out now and will report back. It seems more like a workaround, since it requires creating and setting a new variable for each field that I want an alias for (I've got more than 100 fields!) But it might be the best option if there is no solution that allows simply modifying where aliases are applied in general.

Comment: you can skip the variable part, and just `edit` the data defined override and enter the new alias within single quotes. That being said, it sounds like a bug and the workaround may not work in future versions.